# Python deque of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue

```
msg = 'afdssav'
MYQ = deque(msg)
MYPQ.append('asdf')
```

Here I am trying to create a deque of strings, however when I pop elements or try to read elements from it using Python 2.7 I get char by char instead.

How can I make it such that it would return the strings the same way I insert them?

i.e. I want `MYQ[1]` to be `'asdf'` and `MYQ.pop()` to return `msg`.

Comment: that's because a string is iterable.

Answer (score 5):

Probably like this:

```
MYQ = deque([msg])
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: from collections import deque

In [2]: msg = 'afdssav'

In [3]: myq = deque([msg])

In [4]: myq.append('asdf')

In [5]: myq
Out[5]: deque(['afdssav', 'asdf'])
```

The call signature of `deque` is:

```
deque([iterable[, maxlen]]) --> deque object
```

Strings are iterable, but when you iterate over a string, you get single characters. Hence the behavior you see:

```
In [7]: deque(msg)
Out[7]: deque(['a', 'f', 'd', 's', 's', 'a', 'v'])
```

You want to give `deque` an iterable that would produce the entire string.